# Scala logical indexing with for comprehension

Tags: arrays, matlab, scala

I'm trying to translate the following Matlab logical-indexing pattern into Scala code:

```
% x is an [Nx1] array of Int32
% y is an [Nx1] array of Int32
% myExpensiveFunction() processes batches of unique x.

ux = unique(x);
z = nan(size(x));
for i = 1:length(ux)
  idx = x == ux(i);
  z(idx) = myExpensiveFuntion(x(idx), y(idx));
end
```

Assume I'm working with `val x: Array[Int]` in Scala.  What is the best way to do this?

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm looking to process batches of (x,y) at a time, grouped by unique x, and return a result (z) with an order corresponding to the initial input.  I'm open to sorting x, but eventually need to get back to the original unsorted order. My primary requirement is to handle all the indexing/mapping/sorting in a clear and reasonably efficient way.

Comment: For those who don't know MatLab, could you clarify what computation you want to do?

Comment: IIRC: Matlab's `unique` returns the unique values in `x` which translates to a `Set` in Scala. The expression `idx = x == ux(i);` gives a boolean vector of indices, which correspond to a certain unique value. `z`, `x`, and `y` are projected/reduced to these indices.

Comment: @RandallSchulz - The weirdest part to a Scala-user is that in matlab, if you index a vector with a binary vector, it will use that as a filter for which indices to use.  Simple enough, except _you can assign into your filter_.  So `z(a) = y(a)+1` will set each element of `z` equal to the corresponding element of `y` plus one for exactly those element indices where `a` is true (actually, 1).

Comment: It sounds like it would be fun to implement a MatLab like library / toolkit / framework in Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is pretty straightforward in Scala; the only thing that's a bit out of the ordinary is the unique `x` indices.  In Scala you'd do that with a `groupBy'.  Since this is a really index-heavy method, I'm just going to give in and go with indices all the way:

```
val z = Array.fill(x.length)(Double.NaN)
x.indices.groupBy(i => x(i)).foreach{ case (xi, is) =>
  is.foreach(i => z(i) = myExpensiveFunction(xi, y(i)))
}
z
```

assuming you can live with a lack of vectors going to `myExpensiveFunction`.  If not,

```
val z = Array.fill(x.length)(Double.NaN)
x.indices.groupBy(i => x(i)).foreach{ case (xi, is) =>
  val xs = Array.fill(is.length)(xi)
  val ys = is.map(i => y(i)).toArray
  val zs = myExpensiveFunction(xs, ys)
  is.foreach(i => z(i) = zs(i))
}
z
```

This isn't the most natural way to do the computation in Scala, or the most efficient, but you don't care about efficiency if your expensive function is expensive, and it's the closest I can come to a literal translation.

(Translating your matlab-algorithms into almost everything else involves a certain amount of pain or rethinking, since the "natural" computations in matlab are not like those in most other languages.)

Comment: Thanks Rex. Could you expand on a more Scala-esque/efficient way to do this as well?

Comment: @chriswynnyk - Well, no, because I have no idea why I have an expensive function that likes a vector of identical `x` values and a bunch of nonidentical `y`s, and why the answers need to be kept aligned with the original order fo the `y`s.

Comment: @chriswynnyk - I did at least suggest a per-element `myExpensiveFunction` variant.

Answer (score 0):

The important point is to get Matlab's `unique` right. A simple solution would be to use a `Set` to determine the unique values:

```
val occurringValues = x.toSet

occurringValues.foreach{ value =>
  val indices = x.indices.filter(i => x(i) == value)
  for (i <- indices) {
    z(i) = myExpensiveFunction(x(i), y(i))
  }
}
```

Note: I assume that it is possible to change `myExpensiveFunction` to element-wise operation...

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> def process(xs: Array[Int], ys: Array[Int], f: (Seq[Int], Seq[Int]) => Double): Array[Double] = {
     |   val ux = xs.distinct
     |   val zs = Array.fill(xs.size)(Double.NaN)
     |   for(x <- ux) {
     |     val idx = xs.indices.filter{ i => xs(i) == x }
     |     val res = f(idx.map(xs), idx.map(ys))
     |     idx foreach { i => zs(i) = res }
     |   }
     |   zs
     | }
process: (xs: Array[Int], ys: Array[Int], f: (Seq[Int], Seq[Int]) => Double)Array[Double]

scala> val xs = Array(1,2,1,2,3)
xs: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 1, 2, 3)

scala> val ys = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
ys: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val f = (a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) => a.sum/b.sum.toDouble
f: (Seq[Int], Seq[Int]) => Double = <function2>

scala> process(xs, ys, f)
res0: Array[Double] = Array(0.5, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666, 0.6)
```